# TAGS for Revisions

Tags: discussion

Do you think we need to make TAGS for revisions of PCB's ?

Sometimes hardware questions and their answers will depend on if it's the early PCB or the slightly newer ones or complete new ones, possibly even much newer revisions to come. All those changes could mean various solutions and limitations on various versions. Also clicking on a tag then would expose all relevant Q&A for those specific versions only.. possibly?

Comment: Can you provide an example question?